# $stateChangeSuccess not called

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have a refresh function that invokes $state.go(). In some instances the $stateChangeSuccess handler is being called, and others it's not, but I don't understand why. I need the state change handler to fire.

refresh function

```
$scope.refresh = function( group ) {
  ...
  $state.go($state.current.name, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    location: true,
    inherit: true,
    relative: $state.$current,
    notify: true
  });
```

$stateChangeSuccess handler

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function( event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams ) {
  console.log('$stateChangeSuccess handler called');
});
```

I'm wondering if there could be something that prevents the $stateChangeSuccess handler from being called? I thought there might be a $stateChangeStart handler canceling the operation, but there isn't.

Comment: Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution or explanation?  I'm having the same problem. Thanx for your help.